# sequelize beforeCreate hook not called

Tags: sequelize.js

Im defining my beforeCreate hook using direct method (Method 3 in sequelize docs) like this:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, datatypes)=>{
    var tag = sequelize.define(...)

    tag.beforeCreate(tag,options=>{...})

    tag.beforeBulkCreate(tags,options=>{...})
}
```

beforeBulkCreate is being fired when I do tag.bulkCreate but beforeCreate is not when I do tag.create. Why is that?

Answer (score 3):

You should use `individualHooks: true` if you want to run create hooks for each row http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/#bulkcreaterecords-options-promisearrayinstance

Comment: Is there anyway to turn on individualHooks as part of the model options? Seems non-intuitive, from an API perspective, for callers of bulkCreate to know they have to pass along the option.

Answer (score 0):

I felt it was important to default individualHooks to be true when defining my model as opposed to assuming all callers of bulkCreate would know to pass {individualHooks: true}. The first response is correct, but I think it would be better to control how hooks are used within the Model definition and not make the caller responsible.

This is what I did in my model definition.

```
var baseBulkCreate = User.bulkCreate;
User.bulkCreate = function(instances, options) {
    options = options || {};

    // We want to make sure that when we do things in bulk we always run the individual hooks too.  It isn't clear
    // why this isn't the default.
    options.individualHooks = true;

    return baseBulkCreate.call(this, instances, options);
};
```